# Получить количество неповторяющихся чисел в зависимости от системы исчисления.(оптимизация)

Tags: python

Неповторяющееся число, то число где все цифры в числе не повторяются, например 53498

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать так, чтобы код не вычислял все возможные последовательности, потому что при системе исчисления, например, в 10 тратится очень большое количество памяти и я в, принципе, понимаю, что есть какой то вариант просто прибавлять счетчик не сохраняя данные каждого множества.

Вот пример моего кода:

```
def non_repeats(radix):
   from itertools import permutations
   thelist = [x for x in range(radix)]
   arr = []
   if len(thelist) > 0:
       for r in range(0,len(thelist)+1):
            arr += list(permutations(thelist, r))
   n = len(arr)
   for i in range(1, len(arr)-1):
       if arr[i][0] == 0:
           n -= 1
   return n-1
print(non_repeats(6))
```

Comment: Где точная формулировка задачи?

Comment: https://www.matematicus.ru/kombinatorika-2/sochetanie-bez-povtorenij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
import math

def count_non_repeats(radix):
    cnt = radix
    for i in range(2, radix + 1):
        cnt += (radix-1)*math.perm(radix-1, i-1)
    return cnt

>> 3  11  49  261  1631  11743  95901  876809  8877691
```

Откуда взялось: на первом месте в k-значном числе может стоять любая из цифр 1..radix-1, а после идёт любое из размещений выборки k-1 цифр из остальных цифр 0..radix-1, не включая уже задействованную цифру, таких размещений `A(radix-1, i-1)`

Comment: вставлю свои 5 копеек: `count_non_repeats = lambda r: r + (r - 1) * sum(math.perm(r - 1, i) for i in range(1, r))`

Comment: @Zhihar А, вот они -  размещения, а я через сочетания+факториал делал, спасибо!

Comment: Всем спасибо!  Решение то что нужно